# PHP read content and do a preg_match

Tags: php

I am trying to get the font-family only if the selector is starting with @font-face, and breaks if selector is not starting with @font-face, but below do not seem to work.

#### CSS file content:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'someFonts'; 
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'someotherFonts';    
}

.style {
  font-family: 'someFonts';
}
```

**PHP:**

```
$content = file_get_contents($file->uri);
if (!preg_match('#@font-face {([^;]+);#i', $content, $matches)) {
  break;
}

$fonts = array();
if (preg_match_all('#font-family:([^;]+);#i', $content, $matches)) {
  foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    if (preg_match('#"([^"]+)"#i', $match, $font_match)) {
      $fonts[] = $font_match[1];
    }
    elseif (preg_match("#'([^']+)'#i", $match, $font_match)) {
      $fonts[] = $font_match[1];
    }
  }
}
```

Any hint is very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So you only want the font-family names inside of `@font-face` blocks, or only want font-family names where they are defined in `@font-face` *and* are used elsewhere?

Comment: Just to make sure, if you echo the $content, you get a response that is the exact same as the first quote?

Comment: I do not want to read .style. The code should stop reading when non @font-face block is found.

Comment: For the record, running this http://pastebin.com/Di30Nv31 works..

Comment: Thanks, seems the issue is on the below code. It was an old try, and when revisited this now with several files to read, I just found the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding about how `preg_match()` works. Your `if()` condition always evaluates true, because there actually is `@font-face { .. }` *somewhere* in the file.

You can use `preg_match_all()` to find all defined font-families inside a `@font-face` selector like this:

```
$fonts = array();
$content = file_get_contents($file->uri);

if( preg_match_all('=@font-face\s*{.*font-family: (.*)[\s|;].*}=isU', 
       $content, 
       $matches) ) {
    $fonts = array_merge($fonts, $matches[1]);
}

print_r($fonts);
```

Result:

```
Array ( 
       [0] => 'someFonts' 
       [1] => 'someotherFonts' 
) // the second "someFonts" from your class ".style" is not included in the list!
```

Comment: Thanks, that do the tricks. Seems my additional codes are useless

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure its not working?  I have no problem with the following code -

```
$content = "@font-face {
  font-family: 'someotherFonts';    
}

.style {
  font-family: 'someFonts';
}";

if (!preg_match('#@font-face {([^;]+);#i', $content, $matches)) {
  echo "didnt find match";
}
else{
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Does the above code work for you?

Possible issues could be
1. Its not reading correctly from the file. Try echoing $content.
2. It works, and there was some oversight while checking. Try echoing $matches in an else block.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with regex:

```
#@font-face\s*\{\s*(([^:]+)\s*:\s*([^;]+);\s*)+?\s*}#i
```

it will match any `@font-face` declaration (single or multiline)